# Swift optional parameter functions

Tags: ios, xcode, function, swift, option-type

So I have the following function:

```
func remoteCall(_url:String, _params:[String: String]?=nil){
   ...


   ...
   Alamofire.request(.POST, _url, parameters: _params)   //requires _params to be of type [String String!]

   ...
}
```

As you can see, I can do:

```
let url = "https://eamorr.com/remote.php"
remoteCall(url)    //works great!
```

Or, I can do:

```
let url = "https://eamorr.com/remote.php"
let params = [
    "email": "eamorr@eamorr.com",
    "pword": "secret"
]
remoteCall(url, _params:params)   //works great!
```

However, what I can't do is:

```
let url = "https://eamorr.com/remote.php"
let params = [
    "email": email.text,   //where "email" is a UITextField
    "pword": pword.text    //where "pword" is a UITextField
]
remoteCall(url, _params:params)   //this doesn't work
```

I get this error:

`'String!' is not identical to 'String'`

**I need to be able to accomodate all three situations (pass nothing, pass raw strings, and pass UITextField values)**

Unfortunately, if I try to change the function signature (note the '!' after the keyword "String") to:

```
func remoteCall(_url:String, _params:[String: String!]?=nil){
   ...

   ...
}
```

The UITextField values work, passing nil works, but the raw strings situation fails at run-time.

`fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes`

`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`

I'll be using this function a lot, so I would like not to have to wrap my "params" variable up in messy code.

I'm new to Swift, an Objective-C head, and trying to re-learn everything again...

I guess if I can somehow convert any incorrect `[String: String]` to `[String: String!]` neatly inside the function without disturbing any `nil`'s or `[String: String!]`'s that already work?

Comment: a pretty clean way might be to use the nilCoalescing operator `??` i.e. `let params = [ "email": email.text ?? "", "pword": pword.text ?? "" ]` the `??` operator chooses the left hand argument unless it is nil. Basically it lets you  provide a default value in case your Optional is nil. (is should also unwrap your optional in this case)

Comment: JMFR Hi, thank you for your very good suggestion. No way I would have thought of this way. I think I will go with @AntonBronnikov's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
let url = "https://eamorr.com/remote.php"
let params: [String: String] = [ // Note explicitly declared type
    "email": email.text,   //where "email" is a UITextField
    "pword": pword.text    //where "pword" is a UITextField
]
remoteCall(url, _params:params)
```

Problem in your case was that without explicit type declaration Swift will infer one for you.  Both values in the dictionary you create are of `String!` type, which is *different* from `String`.  Hence the error.  If you explicitly tell Swift that `params` is of `[String: String]` type that should work fine because it is ok to assign `String!` value to a `String` variable.

Comment: Very good. Thank you for your help. I wonder is it possible to do it inside the function? Ideally, I wouldn't need the extra syntax, but I guess if it's a good reliable way of doing it; I'm happy!

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible inside of function in concise and efficient manner.  What I can think of is _another_ `remoteCall` function with `[String: String!]` signature for `params`, which would simply convert `[String: String!]` into `[String: String]` and then call the original function.  This approach would give you the flexibility you want.  Although, casting `[String: String!]` dictionary to `[String: String]` is a task of O(N) complexity (and that could hurt if you have huge dictionaries), from the example you gave this does not seem to be a problem.